# Chida's statement about shabbat violators

Tags: shabbat, history, sources-mekorot, rabbis, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern

I heard Rabbi Yitzhack Yosef Shelita (Rishon LeTzion and son of Maran HaRav Ovadia Yosef, Z"L)  who says that the Chida writes that in all the places that he was never saw a Sephardic Jew that wasn't Shomer Shabbat.

Does anyone have the source of this?

Comment: The WP article is about the Ben Ish Chai, not the Chida.

Comment: True, my bad. (I've deleted the offending comment.)